# I have a issue in the below query

Tags: sql-server-2008

**Employee Table:**

```
ID Name Date   Active Salary
1   A   1/04     1     2000
2   B   1/04     0     2000
3   C   3/05     1     4000
4   A   5/05     1     4000
5   B   16/05    1     9000
6   A   2/05     1     3000
7   D   3/08     0    12000
```

**Desired Output #1:** This is the sum and count of all records per name.

```
Name Count Salary
A      3    9000
B      2   11000
C      1    4000
D      1   12000
```

**Desired Output #2:** This is the sum of *all* records but the count of only *active* records per name.

```
Name Count Salary
A      3    9000
B      1   11000
C      1    4000
D      0   12000
```

Comment: You have not an issue, you want us to do your work.

Comment: Did you at least try to write your own SQL? If so, let us know what you tried and what specific issues you are having - instead of having us write your code, like @Time Schmelter suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some general advice which should be enough to lead you to a solution without actually doing all the work for you.

Now I suppose I should assume that you know this but, on the off chance you're a *complete* beginner, you can select certain columns from a table with something like (could be in any order):

```
sql> select name, salary from employees
A   2000
B   2000
C   4000
A   4000
B   9000
A   3000
D  12000
```

You can also filter certain rows from the data with a `where` clause, such as only getting those with a salary 4000 or less (again, no guarantee of order):

```
sql> select name, salary from employees
...> where salary <= 4000
A   2000
B   2000
C   4000
A   4000
A   3000
```

And you can group rows together based on a common criteria, such as getting the "earliest" name for each possible salary value but also with a count of each row making up the group (for example, there are two rows for the `2000` salary, one row for `9000`):

```
sql> select min(name), count(*), salary from employees
...> group by salary
A   2    2000
A   2    4000
A   1    3000
B   1    9000
D   1   12000
```

That's pretty much all you need to get the results you want, you just need to apply that knowledge in slightly different ways:

- you only need to **select** the `name` and `salary` information from the table, you have no interest in showing date or active flag;
- you need to **group** the rows **by** the `name`, and **count** each row for the groups; and
- you're interested int the **sum** of the salaries, rather than the minimum of the names.

That should be enough to be getting on with, provided you realise I didn't bold those words above because I like playing with different font properties :-)

---

Since more than enough time has now passed to make whether or not this was classwork moot, see the following schema setup and query to deliver what you want:

```
create table empl (
  id     integer,
  name   varchar(20),
  dt     date,
  actv   integer,
  sal    integer);
insert into empl(id,name,dt,actv,sal) values (1,'A','4/01/2015',1, 2000);
insert into empl(id,name,dt,actv,sal) values (2,'B','4/01/2015',0, 2000);
insert into empl(id,name,dt,actv,sal) values (3,'C','5/03/2015',1, 4000);
insert into empl(id,name,dt,actv,sal) values (4,'A','5/05/2015',1, 4000);
insert into empl(id,name,dt,actv,sal) values (5,'B','5/16/2015',1, 9000);
insert into empl(id,name,dt,actv,sal) values (6,'A','5/02/2015',1, 3000);
insert into empl(id,name,dt,actv,sal) values (7,'D','8/03/2015',0,12000);

select     name,
           count(1) as count,
           sum(sal) as salary
from       empl
group by   name
```

This gives, as desired:

```
name  count  salary
----  -----  ------
A         3    9000
B         2   11000
C         1    4000
D         1   12000
```

That covers your first case. Your second case is a little trickier since you want all the salaries for each name summed but you only want to count the active records. This can be done with a self-joining sub-query:

```
select   e1.name, 
         (select count(1)
          from   empl e2
          where  e2.name = e1.name
            and  e2.actv = 1) as count,
         sum(e1.sal) as salary
from     empl e1
group by name
```

With this slightly modified query, you get:

```
name  count  salary
----  -----  ------
A         3    9000
B         1   11000
C         1    4000
D         0   12000
```